# Why does "...at once" sound fine but "...right now" doesn't?

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, adverbs

A non English native colleague asked a questioned today that I couldn't answer clearly. The only thing I could come up with was that it sounded strange. The sentences:

"They liked him almost at once."

and

"They liked him almost right now."

I mentioned that if almost was taken out, either would be fine (at least it sounds fine to me).

Can anyone give a detailed explanation as to why right now sounds weird?

edit: Also can anyone give a grammatical explanation why?

Comment: "right now" refers to the current moment in time. "at once" could be replaced by "immediately" or "as soon as they met him" because those refer to the moment they met him, and not to the current moment.

Comment: “Right away” works.

Comment: @mRotten I see! That clears it up a little when you put it like that. Thank you for your explanation. But would you happen to know why grammatically?

Comment: It might be  because in right now,  the absoluteness  of now is accentuated with right, and then if we try to 'dilute' it with _almost_, the effect is strange.    In right away , away does not  have an absolute nature, so an almost added before that does not sound so strange. Right now I cannot think of other examples though.

Comment: As @mRotten says, 'right now' can only refer to the present moment, so it makes no sense to use it with the past tense (liked).

Comment: @KateBunting In fact the OP was wrong in saying that removing 'almost' from "they liked him almost right now" makes it right because, as you say, 'right now' can't be in the past. 'Right now" can be replaced by "at this very moment" but if you are talking about the past you have to say at _that_ very moment". The past equivalent of "right now" is "right then".

Comment: ... And 'right then' is not as common as 'right now'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, but "right then and there" is a standard phrase.